# Как собрать дату из двух серий в Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

UPD:
Как собрать дату из двух серий (месяц, день)? Несмотря на простоту вопроса и ознокомления с документацией к `pandas`, решения не нашёл.

Пример серий:

```
    Month       Year
0   February    2017
1   July        2017
2   November    2017
3   September   2017
4   August      2017
5   March       2017
6   March       2017
7   August      2017
8   March       2017
9   March       2017
10  August      2017
```

В результате требуется получить серию Period типа February 2017. Тип данных нужен дата.

Comment: Какого тип данных нужен для нового столбца? Если дата, то выглядеть это будет как `2017-02-01`, а если Period, то: `2017-02`

Comment: Обновил вопрос в соответствии с комментарием

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создать новый столбец с типом `datetime`:

```
In [65]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.astype(str).add(' ').sum(1))

In [66]: df
Out[66]:
        Month  Year       Date
0    February  2017 2017-02-01
1        July  2017 2017-07-01
2    November  2017 2017-11-01
3   September  2017 2017-09-01
4      August  2017 2017-08-01
5       March  2017 2017-03-01
6       March  2017 2017-03-01
7      August  2017 2017-08-01
8       March  2017 2017-03-01
9       March  2017 2017-03-01
10     August  2017 2017-08-01

In [67]: df.dtypes
Out[67]:
Month            object
Year              int64
Date     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Чтобы создать новый столбец с типом `Period`:

```
In [69]: df['Period'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.astype(str).add(' ').sum(1)), freq='M')

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
        Month  Year  Period
0    February  2017 2017-02
1        July  2017 2017-07
2    November  2017 2017-11
3   September  2017 2017-09
4      August  2017 2017-08
5       March  2017 2017-03
6       March  2017 2017-03
7      August  2017 2017-08
8       March  2017 2017-03
9       March  2017 2017-03
10     August  2017 2017-08

In [71]: df.dtypes
Out[71]:
Month     object
Year       int64
Period    object
dtype: object

In [72]: df.Period.dt.days_in_month
Out[72]:
0     28
1     31
2     30
3     30
4     31
5     31
6     31
7     31
8     31
9     31
10    31
Name: Period, dtype: int64
```

Comment: MaxU, большое спасибо! Мне как раз нужен первый из предложенных вами вариантов. Где дата в виде первого числа каждого месяца. Единственное, мне не очень понятно, зачем вы используете sum(1). Кажется можно просто результат функции add вложить в pd.to datetime или я что-то не допонял?

Comment: @DenisNovik, если в вашем DF присутствуют и другие столбцы то надо выбрать только два необходимых: df[[“Month”,”Year”]].astype(str).add(' ').sum(1)

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, MaxU